# Fiware Draco cant acess localhost:8080

Tags: fiware

I install Draco via docker and when i try acess **localhost:8080/nifi**
The browser show this message "localhost not sending data"

I tried ro restart but nothing

Pls help...

Comment: Hi, the new version of Draco that is aligned with the latest NiFi version, changes the default web port ta *8443*. Also, now you need to login using the following credentials in the login page: -  user: admin -  password: pass1234567890. Now, if you are using the docker-compose file that we provide in the repository, the web interface url is: https://localhost:9090/nifi/ otherwise the login page should be accessed using the default port.

Answer (score 0):

If you are following the tutorial [here](https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.Historic-Context-NIFI), then **Draco** can be configured as follows:

```yaml
  # Draco is configured to write context data to a database
  draco:
    image: ging/fiware-draco:${DRACO_VERSION}
    hostname: draco
    container_name: fiware-draco
    networks:
      - default
    environment:
      - NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT=${DRACO_API_PORT}
    expose:
      - "5050"
      - "${DRACO_API_PORT}"
    ports:
      - "${DRACO_API_PORT}:${DRACO_API_PORT}" # localhost:9090
      - "5050:5050"
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --fail -s http://draco:${DRACO_API_PORT}/nifi-api/system-diagnostics || exit 1
      start_period: 1m
```

According to the `.env` file, the web port is `9090` not `8080`

```
# Draco Variables
DRACO_VERSION=1.3.6
DRACO_API_PORT=9090
```

You should check  your ports using the `docker ps` command.